# link doesn't clickable on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

The menu links in one of my site doesn't work on mobile display and I can't figure out why.

Here's the site:
http://www.ayamedical.co.il/

Try to click on some of the link in the primary menu on mobile view.
The only thing I change is some java script in order to fix problem with the sub-menus, but I don't see how it cause this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var screenWidth = $(window).width();

    if ( screenWidth < 768 ){

        $('.main-navigation ul li a').toggle(function() {
            $(this).next().css('left', 'auto');
        }, function() {
            $(this).next().css('left', '-9999px');
        });

    }
});
```

What's going on?

Comment: What do you want to do with this javascript?

Comment: show/hide the sub-menus, because it doesn't work without it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add every top menu which has sub-menu `a` tag `href="#"` attribute and after that you should change the javascript to that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var screenWidth = $(window).width();

    if ( screenWidth < 768 ){

        $('.main-navigation>ul>li>a[href="#"]').toggle(function() {
            $(this).next().css('left', 'auto');
        }, function() {
            $(this).next().css('left', '-9999px');
        });

    }
});
```